# QueryDict coming through in django instead of JSON when AJAXing

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have like 8 ajax calls on a javascript page.

7 are like so, and go to the same view in python in Django for parsing and stuff:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/apiForStuff",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({'boxStuff': stuff}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        table.reload()
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
    }
});
```

1 is like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/otherAPIStuff",
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            table.reload()
            
        },
        'error': function(err) {
            console.log('err', err)
        }
    });
```

The view called by the first one (and six like it):

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class StuffUpdater(LayerDetailMixin, ApplicationDomainMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        post_request = json.loads(request.POST)
```

The print statement prints a  QueryDict, and json.loads proceeds to fail with:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict
```

Comment: try `json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: you don't need to convert it into JSON it's already an object.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: dude, it's the simple things ;-) write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is convert [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)( a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object which is already converted by Django using request body) into a dictionary using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) (which expects only `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` instances).

If you need to access raw or non-form data posted in the request, access it through the [**`request.body`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) attribute instead.

---

Here is an excerpt from [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST):

### `request.POST/request.GET`

> In an **HttpRequest** object, the **GET** and **POST** attributes are
> instances of `django.http.QueryDict`, a dictionary-like class
> customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. This is
> necessary because some HTML form elements, notably ,
> pass multiple values for the same key.
>
> The QueryDicts at `request.POST` and `request.GET` will be immutable
> when accessed in a normal request/response cycle. To get a mutable
> version you need to use `request.POST.copy()` or `request.GET.copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `json.loads`, by definition, this method should be used for
deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

By definition, in an `HttpRequest` (django) object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of `django.http.QueryDict`, a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key.

So, you can convert a `QueryDict` to `dict`, like this.

```
myDict = dict(queryDict.iterlists())
```